# How do I get all items in the array that is type defined as item(index: number): any;

Tags: typescript, react-native, sqlite

I'm working on a react native project but this is more of a typescript question. I have the SQLite embedded db wired up and I want to retrieve the whole array of rows. The problem is that the object looks like this

[image]

So as you can see `_array` is meant to be private and is not included in the type definition. The type definitions are like so

```js
export interface SQLResultSet {
  insertId: number;
  rowsAffected: number;
  rows: SQLResultSetRowList;
}

export interface SQLResultSetRowList {
  length: number;
  item(index: number): any;
}
```

I've come up with three solutions but I'm not totally happy with any of them.

1. Casting `SQLResultSet.rows` as `any` (worse option as I lose my type checking).
2. Using the `length` property to make calls to `SQLResultSet.rows.item()`, iterating over all of them and building the array from there (also not ideal because it's extra code that feels messy).
3. Making my own interface extending `SQLResultSetRowList` to add the `_array: any[]` field (what I'm currently doing and at least I don't lose my type checks with that).

But, ideally, I want to know if there is some typescript syntax for working with a function as it's defined in `item(index: number): any;` where I can simply get that all as an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const resultSet:SQLResultSet  = ...;
const allItems = Array.from(resultSet.rows, (_, i) => resultSet.rows.item(i));
```

See [`Array.from(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you should access _array directly, because it would be an interface implementation error for the library, and if it's not, it's private so you should not access it. But if it's ok, I think the extending way is the best one, as you suggested

Comment: It looks like including `_array` in the type definition is going to be a part of the next expo release. https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/13826